# cant see variables from other class

Tags: java, netbeans

My problem is simple, even for my Java 1 class, but I can't seem to figure this out.  Why can't my main class see variables that were initialized in another?  I am using NetBeans.  I am creating project Test123, then a class TestStuff.  Both use package test123.  They are in the same src folder that NetBeans sends them to.

```
package test123;

public class Test123 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    help = "hi";
    thank = "hello";

}

}
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
package test123;

public class TestStuff {
String help;
String thank;

public void weee(){

System.out.print("yay");
help = "me";
thank = "you";

}
}
```

Comment: you did not create and instance of TestStuff class in Test123. thus even if they are in same package, they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `help` and `thank` are **instance variables**.  If you create an object of type `TestStuff`, then that object will contain variables `help` and `thank`.  (And if you create more objects of type `TestStuff`, each object will have its own `help` and `thank` variables.)  To get to them, you have to create an object whose type is `TestStuff` (i.e. an **instance** of `TestStuff`), and then access the variables belonging to that object:

```
TestStuff testObject = new TestStuff();
testObject.help = "hi";
testObject.thank = "hello";
```

You only need to do that outside the `TestStuff` class, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create an instance of TestStuff Class like:

```
TestStuff testobject= new TestStuff();
testobject.help="hii";
testobject.thank="hello"
```

put this code in class Test123 inside main() method.
to get access to variables bind to object of TestStuff class.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `help` and `thank` are declared in a class and known as **instance variable**. Each instance of the class will have its own copy of those variables. You should declare them private and provide getter/setter to access them.

```
    public class TestStuff {
        private String help;
        private String thank;

        public String getHelp() {
            return help;
        }

        public void setHelp(String help) {
            this.help = help;
        }

        public String getThank() {
            return thank;
        }

        public void setThank(String thank) {
            this.thank = thank;
        }

        public void weee() {
            System.out.println("yay");
            help = "me";
            thank = "you";
            }
     }
```

Then you can create an instance of that class and invoke method wee on that instance. It will change the value of the variables `help` and `thank` for that instance.

```
public class Test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestStuff testStuff = new TestStuff();
        System.out.println("Before: " + testStuff.getHelp() + " " + testStuff.getThank());
        testStuff.weee();
        System.out.println("After: " + testStuff.getHelp() + " " + testStuff.getThank());
    }
}
```

And as expected the output will be:
Before: null null
yay
After: me you